# Problem about Copying the weight from pytorch model to tf2 model

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I try to copy the weights from a pytorch model to tf2 model.
I can successfully do the influence.
I output the feature map to have a look.
However, the feature map after a conv2d has black bars on the top and left hand side of the map.[image]

The pytorch feature map does not have these black bars.
The pytorch code of conv2d is nn.Conv2d(1, 56, kernel_size=5, padding=5//2)
The tensorflow build is Conv2D(56, 5, padding="same")(inp)
The copying weight from pytorch model to tf2 is :

```
onnx_1_w_num = onnx_l.weight.data.permute(2,3,1,0).numpy()
onnx_1_b_num = onnx_l.bias.data.numpy()
tf_l.set_weights([onnx_1_w_num,onnx_1_b_num])
```

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: anyone is familar with that? Many thanks

Comment: The input size of the image is (600,720,1) and the output is also (600,720,1). But the output put feature map has the black bar as shown above.